# Only one usage of each socket is normally permitted

Tags: windows, sockets

Trying to listen on an already-used port (for example, running two instances of the same socket server) on Windows gives:

> [WinError 10048] Only one usage of each socket address
>   (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted

I'm confused why only one usage of each address is *normally* permitted. I was under the impression this was an absolute rule (at least on Unix), but apparently not. In what cases (and how) could there be two programs using the same socket address? Or am I misinterpreting this error?

Comment: I'm confused why you think error message are that precise.

Comment: yeah, I guess undue optimism in microsoft

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not an absolute rule on all UNIX systems.  Some have extensions that allow multiple processes to bind to the same address and port combination, and the kernel will then handle distributing incoming connections to the multiple listeners.  The advantage of this is that your application doesn't need to handle multiplexing the connections itself, and can instead just worry about handling connections, which in turn gives you a quick and very easy to implement mechanism to allow parallelism in your networking code.

On Linux, the socket option for this is called `SO_REUSEPORT`, and a lot of widely used high-performance server software (including stuff like Apache HTTPD and nginx) supports using it.

Windows, because it uses a largely direct clone of the 4.4BSD networking code, has the same concept of socket options, and has its own options for controlling this.  According to [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17980407/two-listeners-on-the-same-port), the option in question there is called `SO_REUSEADDR`, and there is a equivalent 'anti-option' called `SO_EXCLUSIVEADDRUSE`.

It's worth noting that there is nothing that prevents multiple *different* programs from using this option and binding to the same port.  This can lead to all kinds of headaches when debugging networking problems, and is also a rather significant security consideration.